# redirection in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

In my home page i have a profile pic on changing the profile pic i update the DB and redirevt the page to /home . But now when i redirect the old picture remains the same till refresh button is hit.Ami doing anything wrong here

This is in the python code

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
```

This is in the base html page in /home

```
   <img src="{{photo}}" ></img>
```

Comment: Is the `src` attribute of your `img` tag changing between after the redirect and you hitting refresh? If so, then my bet is on your browser's cache being the problem, and you should make sure that changing the profile picture results in a new URL. If not, then something in your view is at fault.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the profile picture is cached by the browser. There are multiple ways to avoid it:

- disable caching for the by changing the response headers for it. This is a **bad idea** for production because the picture would never be cached, so every page-request would fetch the picture, which massively increases the traffic
- change the filename of the photo when it is update. You could i.e. use a hash of the content or something like `SHA1(userid + timestamp of upload)`
- use a [HTTP ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) in the response header of the picture

Answer (score 1):

There's a trick I read that consists in writing something like:

`<img src="{{photo}}?version={{version}}"></img>`

Where version is a new version number that you increase when your file is updated (you could alternatively use `{{photo.file}}` and `{{photo.version}}`).
This way the URL will be different and the browser will not used the cached version.

Comment: +1 I use this pretty often. ?v={{ hashed_upload_timestamp }} is nice.

Comment: yup, a timestamp is good, a hash (calculated upon creation) is even better